# Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION returns null on Android 4+

Tags: android, android-sensors

I would like to use the accelerometer data in my application.

I am able to access the `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` without any problems, but many suggest to use the `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` which is already filtered from the earth gravity. It looks like I do not have access to that sensor though, as in the code below the log will return null. 
From what I understand `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` is available as a "software sensor" on Android API greater then 8...I am using 14 as my minimum on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.

Any idea why I get null? Is it because this model does not have a gyroscope?

Code:

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

mLinearAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);

Log.i("TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION", String.valueOf(mLinearAccelerometer));
```

Thanks

Edit: added missing "=" sign

Comment: Is the = (equal sign) after mLinearAccelerometer missing in your actual code?

Comment: Good catch.  I was also going to suggest that perhaps there *is* no linear_acceleration sensor on the device if it has no gyro.  I haven't tested this myself though.

Comment: Just a copy and paste error I guess, equal sign is right there in my code otherwise it would not compile.

Comment: I edited my code adding the equal sign back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the android motion sensor documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html):

> The Android Open Source Project (AOSP) provides three software-based motion sensors: a gravity sensor, a linear acceleration sensor, and a rotation vector sensor. These sensors were updated in Android 4.0 and now use a device's gyroscope ... All three of these sensors rely on a gyroscope: if a device does not have a gyroscope, these sensors do not show up and are not available for use.

.  So your guess is correct, without the gyroscope the gravity sensor is not available.